# Where is John C Polking's DField package?

Tags: reference-request, math-software

Most sites that had a copy are now blank. I am looking for the version that was based on JRE. There used to be a DField and a PPlane.  I am aware of new versions that are tied to MatLab but I am looking for the one that ran without having MatLab.

Comment: Even if you did find them, I'd be surprised if you could get them to run. “[Most mainstream browsers, including Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Safari, and Microsoft Edge, no longer support Java applets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/web-browsers-that-support-java-applets-and-how-to-enable-them)”

Comment: Most shared web math and related areas coding projects are done in things like Google Colab, jupyter notebook, Octave, and the like these days. (At least as it pertains to free options.) I think the vast majority of such things are server-side, not client side like applets used to be.

Comment: @Moo  Thanks. His site was not accessible when I was searching and I thought perhaps he has retired!